# stripping all attributes from an html tag using regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

I've been trying to formulate a regular expression to remove any attributes that may be present in html tags but I'm having trouble doing this and Google doesn't seem to provide any answers either.

Basically my input string looks something like

```
<p style="font-family:Arial;" class="x" onclick="doWhatever();">this text</p>
<img style="border:0px" src="pic.gif" />
```

and I would like to remove any attributes inside the tag to produce a string like:

```
<p>this text</p>
<img src="pic.gif" />
```

Does anybody know a regex for doing this?  I'm using Regex.Replace in C# by the way.

Comment: If you have specific tags you're going to allow, maybe try taking the approach of only *including* those tags, instead of *excluding* everything else.

Comment: That would be because it is very difficult. Attributes can be boolean, have optional (and different kinds of) quotes, if they are quoted they can contain `>` characters and whatever quotes they aren't using already … and that's before you get to *invalid* HTML. Use an HTML parser for this unless you are crafting this for specific documents.

Answer (score 2):

There are really excellent tools for handling this sort of task in .NET without having to resort to the regex hammer. This will also be more reliable than a regular expression based solution.

I'd suggest that you take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Comment: thanks Mark, the HTML Agility pack sounds like it'll do what I want even though it's more code.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is easiest interfaced with using a DOM, but if you really want to do this using a regex you could probably take advantage of that you want to remove *all* attributes, e.g. leave nothing left but the tag. IMO you should use a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score -1):

either that or using jquery each to go trough all html elements and remove attr. or from particular element. Why would you be doing that anyway?

Comment: i have a site that is reusing content which was made using a cms on different site.  The formatting with the style & class attributes looks fine on the site it was intended for but it looks rubbish on the new site and doesn't fit with the design.